# Tensorflow object detection config files documentation

Tags: tensorflow, config

I am using the [object detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) in tensorflow. I noticed that practically all parameters pass through the config file. I could not find any documentation or tutorial on the options for these config files though.

I know that in the official git they provide a [list of config files](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs) for their pretrained models which could be very helpful but it does not cover every case and of course does not provide any explanation if needed.

For example in `train_config` section there are some data augmentation options which are quite self explanatory but the potential existence of other options is unclear:

```
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
```

Is there a source I could refer to? For example in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@WuStangDan/step-by-step-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial-part-4-training-the-model-68a9e5d5a333) two extra options (`batch_queue_capacity` and `prefetch_queue_capacity`) I did not know about appear. Where could I find a decent list of options I have? I know that it's model specific but some of them are universal and really helpful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As mentioned in [the configuration documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md), configuration files are just [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) objects described in the `.proto` files under [`research/object_detection/protos`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/protos). The top level object is a `TrainEvalPipelineConfig` defined in [`pipeline.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/pipeline.proto), and different files describe each of the elements. For example, `data_augmentation_options` are `PreprocessingStep` objects, defined in [`preprocessor.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto) (which in turn can include a range of other possible objects for different preprocessing tasks). The meaning of each object and field may or may not be obvious or well-documented, but you can always refer to the source code to see exactly how each value is being used (for example, check [`preprocessor.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py) to understand how data augmentation is done).

Comment: So why don´t they extend them with .pbtxt instead of .config? This is just confusing, right?

Comment: @EmielBoss Well in principle you should be able to use the framework without even knowing what protocol buffers are, so I suppose `.config` may be more meaningful for many people. However, since there is no proper documentation for the settings besides the `.proto` files, that "complexity hiding" does not quite work so well.

Comment: Just to check whether I have the terminology right: protocol buffers are serialized structured (according to the protocol), like .pbtxt and .pb, right? What would the .proto file itself be called? Just the "protocol"?

Comment: @EmielBoss I'm not sure if there's a very specific terminology about it, but at least what you say makes sense to me fwiw (that is, matches my understanding and I think I'd understand it if I hear it).

Comment: Hi, is there any performance boost if config files are used for model building in contrast to normal way of using tf keras API while building model ?

Comment: Just started wondering how many ways are there for model creation and training in tensorflow ?

Comment: @AshishJohnson The object detection API doesn't do anything that you can't do with plain TensorFlow, it's just an easy-to-use framework that implements models and good training workflows and practices for object recognition, even if you don't have experience on the topic. If you implement the exact same model, input pipeline, etc by yourself in TensorFlow you will get the same performance and results.