# Tensorflow Object Detection - Best practice

Tags: python, object, tensorflow, detection

As mentioned in my other thread ([Tensorflow Object Detection - Avoid overlapping boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538497/tensorflow-object-detection-avoid-overlapping-boxes)) I'm new to machine learning and I have to implement an algorithm for detecting traffic lights.

Regarding Tensorflow and it's possibilities, I've got a whole bunch of questions I don't know where to ask except Stack Overflow.

- For a quick start I've downloaded a pre trained model and started training it using the Bosch Traffic Lights Dataset. Using a pre trained model is fine but every now and then I wonder if it's possible to modify this model (add or remove a layer) or if it would be best to use keras on top of tf for better customization possibilities.
- Additionally I wonder how I should know what are the possible configurations in the pipeline.config file inside every pre trained model. Is there any documentation or do I have to dig into the python files to get into it? In other words, does it even make any sense to change the configuration?
- For documentation purpose we're using tensorboard. Unfortunately there's no accuracy (but loss) documented out of the box - how do we get the accuracy displayed as an additional graph?

Comment: Please prefer to ask only one question per post, that makes it easier to search and answer the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use configuration to tune all the aspects. As mentioned in [Tensorflow object detection config files documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49148962), configuration parameters can be browser in the protocol buffers message definitions. For example, for the model, if you are using faster RCNN, have a look at the different fields of the [`FasterRcnn`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/faster_rcnn.proto) message. You could export a trained model, load it in a regular TensorFlow script and add anything you want to it for whatever purpose, but the object detection framework is meant to be configuration-driven.

For the metrics, have a look at [Supported object detection evaluation protocols](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md). In the [`EvalConfig`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/eval.proto) message, there is a `metrics_set` that you can set to different values for different evaluation metrics.